# Remove bar at secureTextEntry={true}

Tags: react-native

When I use TextInput with `secureTextEntry={true}` props,

It create bar like this.

[image]

(I checked with Red square box)

I want to hide bar above keyboard.

How can I implement it?

Is there any props associated with it?

Below is my TextInput source.

```
    <TextInput
        placeholder="Enter your password"
        autoCorrect={false}
        secureTextEntry={true}
        returnKeyType="done"
        underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
        onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
      />
```

Comment: It might be depend on your keyboard type which you are using... It is not reproduced in iOS with the same config for TextInput.

Comment: haven't tried myself but have you tried setting the keyboardType prop? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardtype